# How to autoformat django html template tags in vscode

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

I've started learning Django and I'm using vs-code.  I'm facing problem in auto-indentation of Django template html tags.  I've tried so many formatters and extensions, searched everywhere, but cannot find a prettier like formatter which can indent the Django-html file template tags.

```
  <div class="col">
      {% if something.someval >= 0 %}
      <p class="card-text">Value: {{ object.value }}</p>
      {% else %}
      <p class="card-text">Value: {{ object.other_val }}</p>
      {% endif %}
  </div>
```

I want this to be indented as:

```
  <div class="col">
      {% if something.someval >= 0 %}
         <p class="card-text">Value: {{ object.value }}</p>
      {% else %}
         <p class="card-text">Value: {{ object.other_val }}</p>
      {% endif %}
  </div>
```

Can anyone please point me to appropriate extension or option?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, check out [djLint](https://github.com/Riverside-Healthcare/djlint), there is a sublimetext linter add-on, but nothing yet for vscode.